# Can you customize the auth0 login screen in xamarin app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, auth0

I have a xamarin app that is utilizing auth0 for auth purposes. But I see for web version you can pass different options for theming the login page appearance. Is that also possible in a xamarin app.

```
 client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
 {
     Domain = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_domain),
     ClientId = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.auth0_client_id),                
     Activity = this
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found you can customize it here: [manage login page](https://manage.auth0.com/#/login_page)

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of configuration options for Lock for Android from Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-android/configuration

I don't see there much of UI-related options. 
Everything you see there you can do in Xamarin as well.